# CSS, floating 2 images in a div each with respective text underneath

Tags: html, css

[image]I have a site/page, http://watershedgeo.staging.wpengine.com/hydroturf/, where I'm trying to float 2 images left in a div and they each have a little text block that needs to go underneath. One block per image.

The issue is that my images are aligned at the top and bottom but the text underneath is way offset currently.

Here is the code for them:

```
<div>
<div class="container1" style="float: left;"><img style="float: left;" src="/HydroTur-CS_illustration-01152104.jpg" /></div>
<div style="float: left;"><span style="color: #0079ac; font-weight: bold;">HydroTurf CS</span>
HydroTurf CS is typically used for high velocity conditions and for protection of critical structures.</div>
<div>
<div class="container2" style="float: left;">
<div><img style="float: left;" src="/HydroTurfZ_illustration-01152014.jpg" /></div>
<div style="float: left;">"<span style="color: #0093d0; font-weight: bold;">HydroTurf Z</span>
HydroTurf Z is ideal for less critical applications involving lower velocities and flow conditions</div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to wrap the image and associated text together in a container, and then you can float the containers.

Comment: @FluffyKitten thanks, but even though that put me in the right direction, the image/text combos are now on top of one another but I need image1/text1 on the left and image2/text2 on the right. I updated my code for the current display though

Comment: float left, float right?

Comment: float left and centered. Added screenshot with the right layout, just offset images

Comment: You may want to look into using either a CSS Grid or Flex box. They're quite powerful at this kind of placement. What you're trying to do is much more complicated, and it's what we had to do before the invention of grids and flex boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify the width of any block element such as a `div`, it will take up 100% of the width. So you need to set the width of your containers to 50% if you want them to take up half the available width, for example.

Also, you don't need to float everything inside the container, the container is its own "block" and you want everything displayed as blocks (i.e. full width and on top of each other) inside it.

You want something like this:

```css
.container { float: left; width:50%; text-align:left; }

/* You won't need the next line, it is simulating the images */
.container img { width:250px; height:150px; background:#FFFF00; display:block; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="/HydroTur-CS_illustration-01152104.jpg" />
<div>
    <span style="color: #0079ac; font-weight: bold;">HydroTurf CS</span> HydroTurf CS is typically used for high velocity conditions and for protection of critical structures.
</div>

</div>
<div class="container">
<img src="/HydroTurfZ_illustration-01152014.jpg" />
<div>
    <span style="color: #0093d0; font-weight: bold;">HydroTurf Z</span> HydroTurf Z is ideal for less critical applications involving lower velocities and flow conditions
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help! That is a very simple example I used, so I suggest doing some online tutorials about using CSS for positioning, as it can get very complex very quickly, especially if you are working on a responsive website.